# Java: ArrayList initializing (difference between 2 code lines)

Tags: java, arraylist

i hope my question won't sound stupid but i'd like to know what's the difference between these two lines:

(Assuming I made a class named Cow..)

```
ArrayList<Cow> c1 = new ArrayList<Cow>();

ArrayList<Cow> c2 = new ArrayList();
```

Thanks in advance for ur explanation.

Comment: Try compiling the code with the javac -Xlint option and see what the compiler has to say about it.

Comment: You will get these annoying warnings in eclipse (for example) if you use the second option : )

Comment: Ye something came up, even by using javac without the 2nd attribute u just gave it notes something, well anyway i dont care much about the tech details i just like to know if the list itself is different in some way..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, there is essentially no difference, due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). The first form is preferred; the second form uses a *raw type*, and is only supported for backward-compatibility with older versions of Java. A good compiler will give you warnings if you use it.

As [the *Java Language Specification*, Third Edition, §4.8](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#110257) explains:

> The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of genericity into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged. **It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types.**

(emphasis in original).

Comment: hm got it! so as u said the list itself is basiclly the same, well explained mate :)

Answer (score 1):

As ruakh has just pointed out, the first one is preferred, and actually there won't be any difference duriong execution.

Explained in simpler words:
In both lines you are declaring a list of *Cow* 
In the first line you instantiate it with a list of *Cow*.
In the second one you instantiate it with a list of Object (and *Cow* is a subclass of *Object*).

It would be even better to declare it as the list interface *List*.

```
List<Cow> listOfCows = new ArrayList<Cow>();
```